# How to retrieve values from arduino to asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, arduino

I am having trouble retrieving values from arduino to a variable in asp.net and then to return it in a chart that is doing return view.

The chart is all done and what i want to do is get the values from the thermostat and add them to the chart

retrieve value code(possibly wrong)

```
void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            float c1 = 1.009249522e-03f, c2 = 2.378405444e-04f, c3 = 2.019202697e-07f;
            float R1 = 10000f;

            SerialPort port;
            string data = string.Empty;

            port = (SerialPort)sender;

            // read the data from the port                                                 
            data = port.ReadExisting();

            // print Arduino data to the screen                                            
            int V0 = Int32.Parse(data);
            double R2 = R1;
            double logR2 = (double)Math.Log(R2);
            double T = (1f / (c1 + c2 * logR2 + c3 * logR2 * logR2 * logR2));

            Tc = T - 273.15f;
            float Tf = (Tc * 9f) / 5f + 32f;
            // you could work with Tc and Tf if you want, (stok data or other)                                              
        }
```

arduino code

```
    int ThermistorPin = 0;
int Vo;
float R1 = 10000;
float logR2, R2, T, Tc, Tf;
float c1 = 1.009249522e-03, c2 = 2.378405444e-04, c3 = 2.019202697e-07;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  Vo = analogRead(ThermistorPin);
  R2 = R1 * (1023.0 / (float)Vo - 1.0);
  logR2 = log(R2);
  T = (1.0 / (c1 + c2*logR2 + c3*logR2*logR2*logR2));
  Tc = T - 273.15;
  Tf = (Tc * 9.0)/ 5.0 + 32.0; 

  Serial.print("Temperature: "); 
  Serial.print(Tf);
  Serial.print(" F; ");
  Serial.print(Tc);
  Serial.println(" C");   

  delay(500);
}
```

Comment: What attempts have you made so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: should i post the code for you to take a look?

Comment: i want to display the the thermostat value on chart in asp.net, i have the chart and the retrieve code but i think that the retrieve code is wrong. What i want to find out is how to take the value and put it on the chart

Comment: In your C# program, you have `data = port.ReadExisting(); int V0 = Int32.Parse(data);`, so you should only have `Serial.println(Vo);` in arduino program. Hope that helps!

Comment: yes but how can i get the value of the Celsius to a variable so i can add that value to the chart?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try it like this:

1.Arduino code:

```
loop{
  Vo = analogRead(ThermistorPin);
  Serial.println(Vo);   
  delay(500);
}
```

2.Then check with Serial Monitor of Arduino software and should see Vo updated by every 0.5 seconds.

3.In C# program, add a TextBox(this is for testing, just make it big, name it as txtInData) to your form.

4.Then try the following C# code,

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        serialPort.Open();
    }
    void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            String data = serialPort.ReadExisting();
            CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
            txtInData.Text += data;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Serial Port Read Error: " + ex.ToString(), "Error");
        }
    }
```

5.Run the C# program and check if you have similar result with step 2. If not, try add `serialPort.DataReceived += serialPort_DataReceived;` after `serialPort.Open();`.

6.You should be able to parse you incoming data now. You may still use the TextBox to check your calculated result. Remove the TextBox when you don't need it anymore.

Hope that helps!